# Spring Autowiring not working on a field that belongs to a class in an external JAR

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I am new to Spring as I inherited an existing project at work that was developed by another company using Spring 3.2.18, and I have come across the following problem:

I am working on application A (app A does not run on a web server), which uses as a dependency project B. I have the source code of B so I build it and include the jars as a maven dependency. Project B contains Class_1, Interface_2 and Class_2 (which implements Interface_2). Class_1 is in org.foo while Interface_2 and Class_2 is in org.toot.

In application A I need to Autowire Class_1 in a TestClass like this:

**TestClass.java**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/test/spring/app-beans.xml"})
public class TestClass{
        @Autowired
        Class_1 class1;

        // do stuff
}
```

**app-beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.foo" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.toot" />

    <bean id="class_1" primary="true" class="org.foo.Class_1"/>

</beans>
```

Now the thing is that Class_1 in project B also has an autowired field:
**Class_1.java**

```
@Service
public class Class_1 {

@Autowired
Interface_2 int2;

}
```

**Interface_2.java**

```
public interface Interface_1 {

// stuff

}
```

**Class_2.java**

```
@Service
public class Class_2 implements Interface_2{

// stuff

}
```

Whenever I try to run my TestClass I get the following error:

```
Could not autowire field: private org.foo.Class_1;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [org.toot.Interface_1]
found for dependency [...]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

What I get from it is that it somehow tries to autowire Class_1 but cannot autowire Interface_2 so it fails. How can I get the implementation of Interface_2 (Class_2) autowired to the field of Class_1? Project B does not have any spring-context files. Can I modify my app-beans.xml in project A to achieve it? Would I have to include context files in project B and re-build? Please share your knowledge and thank you for reading.

Comment: What is package of `Class_2`?

Comment: The package of Class_2 is org.toot